# Create a function in R to compare rows

Tags: r

I want to create a function in R to compare “Current Row Value” and “Previous Row Value.
a.  If Current Row Value is lower than Previous Row Value then return word LOW
b.  If Current Row Value is higher than Previous Value then return word HIGH
c.  If Current Row Value is same as Previous Row Value then return word EQUAL

I want to create a new COLUMN named Decision where the words would be stored like below

Value Decision

1          N/A

2          HIGH

1.5       LOW

1.4       LOW

1.4    EQUAL

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `case_when` to compare the 'Value' with the previous 'Value' (`lag`) and create the column 'Decision' based on whether it is lower or higher

```
library(dplyr)
df1 %>%
 mutate(Decision = case_when(Value < lag(Value) ~ "LOW", 
     Value > lag(Value) ~ "HIGH", Value == lag(Value) ~ "EQUAL"))
#  Value Decision
#1   1.0     <NA>
#2   2.0     HIGH
#3   1.5      LOW
#4   1.4      LOW
#5   1.4    EQUAL
```

---

Or another option is to take the difference and then change the `label`s in `factor`

```
with(df1, c(NA_character_, 
    as.character(factor(sign(Value[-length(Value)] - Value[-1]),         
       levels = c(-1, 1, 0), labels = c("HIGH", "LOW", "EQUAL")))))
#[1] NA      "HIGH"  "LOW"   "LOW"   "EQUAL"
```

---

Or using a `for` loop

```
df1$Decision <- rep(NA_character_, nrow(df1))
for(i in 2: nrow(df1)){
    if(df1$Value[i] > df1$Value[i-1]){
       df1$Decision[i] <- "HIGH"
      } else if(df1$Value[i] < df1$Value[i-1]) {

        df1$Decision[i] <- "LOW"
       } else df1$Decision[i] <- "EQUAL"


   }
```

If it needs to be a function

```
f1 <- function(dat, colNm, newCol) {
  dat[[newCol]] <- rep(NA_character_, nrow(dat))
    for(i in 2: nrow(dat)){
        if(dat[[colNm]][i] > dat[[colNm]][i-1]){
           dat[[newCol]][i] <- "HIGH"
          } else if(dat[[colNm]][i] < dat[[colNm]][i-1]) {

            dat[[newCol]][i] <- "LOW"
           } else dat[[newCol]][i] <- "EQUAL"


       }
     dat
   }

f1(df1, "Value", "Decision")
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(Value = c(1, 2, 1.5, 1.4, 1.4)), class = "data.frame",
     row.names = c(NA, 
-5L))
```

Comment: Can we use an if else loop in a for loop to achieve the same result?

Comment: @prog101 yes, it can achieved

Comment: How can we make a function of the entire loop and feed the arguments to the new function?